# Symbolize only the attribute with a whole number out of a set of decimal numbers

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression

I have a point shapefile of a river network with a point every 100m along the river with the distance to its estuary. The attribute is always a real number like this: 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, ... ,1.0, 1.1, 1.2, and so on.
Since this is quite a lot data, I only want to display the "Integer" value or the whole number, (meaning 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 and so on) in my map. I can do a rule based symbology by using  `if(  "BA_ST_KM" ='0.0',"BA_ST_KM",NULL)`,`if(  "BA_ST_KM" ='1.0',"BA_ST_KM",NULL)` and so one but it just works for one value at the time. Does someone have a solution for all values that are like x.0? Or is there a way to delete als points with the attribute x.1, x.2, x.3 and so on. I'm on QGIS 3.28.04
[image]

Comment: Note that floating-point representation cannot store all possible real values so some comparisons will fail.

Answer (score 5):

- Open "Layer Styling" panel (F7)
- Select "Single Labels"

  [image]
- Use this expression for "Value":

  ```
  if( to_real("BA_ST_KM") % 1 = 0, "BA_ST_KM", NULL )
  ```

This displays the labels for the points which have integer values.

If  your  aim is only to show the symbol of the point which have integer values, then use the same expression for the rule in "Rule-based Symbology".

The `%` symbol in the `to_real("BA_ST_KM") % 1 = 0` part of the expression is a [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo) operator. It returns the remainder from the division of two numbers.  So any number divided by 1 that has a remainder of 0 is a whole number.

Comment: Thank you very much!!